# How to get rid of the voicemail notification?

Tags: voicemail

So I've had this voicemail notification for a few months now and it has started to really bug me. I have actually turned the voicemail system on with my provider so I could check the voicemail and get rid of the notification on my phone but every time I try to call the voicemail number it just says that I have no new voicemails but the notification still stays there!! How do I get rid of it?!

Answer (score 0):

Leave yourself a voicemail. Wait until you get the notification. Then call to listen and delete it. It should go away on its own after a few minutes. If not reboot. If it's still there, call your cellular provider and ask that they clear the Message Waiting Indicator on your account.